# How do we reach app.component from child pages after changing the values in child pages?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In our application, I use translate piping and I store the chosen language in StorageProvider (localstorage)

My Problem is ionic menu (on app.html, app.component) can not be translated to the chosen language when we change the value in child pages. My `app.html` code is given below;

> > app.html

```
    <ion-menu [content]="content">       
      <ion-content class="smrt-dark">
        <ion-list>
          <button  color="dark" menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" style="height: 150%" [hidden]="!isAuthenticate(p.isAccess)">
            <i class="fa fa-{{p.icon}} {{p.color}} circle-i-mn smrt-{{p.color}}" aria-hidden="true" item-start></i>
            {{p.title}}
          </button>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

> > app.component.ts

```
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = LoginPage;
  pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any, icon: string, color: string, isAccess: string }>;
  LANGUAGE;
  constructor(...) {
    console.log('main');
    if ( this.db._config.LANGUAGE === null){
      this.storage.get('language'). then( (data) => {
        this.LANGUAGE = data;
        this.translateService.use(this.db._config.LANGUAGE);

        // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
        this.pages = [
          {title: translateService.instant('home'), component: HomePage, icon: 'home', color: '', isAccess: 'HOME_LIST'},
          {title: translateService.instant('notes'), component: ListNotePage, icon: 'book', color: 'note', isAccess: 'NOTE_LIST'},
          {title: translateService.instant('tasks'), component: ListTaskPage, icon: 'check', color: 'task',  isAccess: 'ISSUE_LIST'}
        ];
      });
    }
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  isAuthenticate(key: string){
    return this.auth.isAuthenticate(key);
  }


  initializeApp()
  {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });

  }
```

If any available methodology to access `app.component.ts` attributes, this solution is also acceptable for me.

Thanks for the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dependency injection to inject a parent component instance into its children, just like you can inject any other class. You just import it:

```
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
```

and then in the constructor of the child component:

```
constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent  ... //other stuff//){
```

Then you will be able to access any public properties and methods available in AppComponent from the child components.

```
this.appComponent.appComponentMethod();
```

or

```
this.appComponent.appComponentProperty = someNewValue;
```

I frequently do this for list, tab, card, etc. components, where a parent is creating N-number of nearly-identical children. I will inject the parent instance into each child, and then create a method in the parent component such as:

```
children: ChildComponent[];

addChild( child : ChildComponent ) {
   this.children.push(child);
}
```

And then, in the child component:

```
constructor( private parent: ParentComponent ) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.parent.addChild(this);
}
```

That way each component, parent and child, has access to each other's public methods and properties. I generally try to manage as much as possible from the parent component and delegate downward as needed.

Comment: Does this solution work in ionic? I try but not works. In constructor some errors occur, LoginPage: (?, [object Object])

Comment: I dont know anything about ionic, so I can't be sure - but on second glance, this won't work in Angular either. I didn't realize it as I was typing it out, but I don't think you can inject App component via dependency injection bc it is the most root component. You'd have to start with at least one sibling down from app component. Can't say for ionic though.